# Proof verification. Show that $\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{O}(f)) = \mathcal{O}(f)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification, asymptotics

> Prove that:
>   $$
> \mathcal{O}(\mathcal{O}(f)) = \mathcal{O}(f)
> $$

I've started with letting some $u \in \mathcal{O}(\mathcal{O}(f))$, then:
$$
|u| \le k_1|v|
$$
Where:
$$
|v| \le k_2|f|
$$

Which means:
$$
|u||v| \le k_1k_2 |v||f| \iff \\ 
|uv| \le k_1k_2 |vf| \iff \\ 
|u| \le k_1k_2 |f| \\
\frac{|u|}{|f|} \le k_1k_2 = C
$$
Now $u\in \mathcal{O}(\mathcal{O}(f))$ by assumption. So we may conclude that:
$$
u = \mathcal{O}(\mathcal{O}(f)) = \mathcal{O}(f)
$$

I'm very new to that notation and comparisons between functions. Could you please verify the above or point to the mistakes/misunderstandings?

Comment: $O$ means big-$\mathcal{O}$?

Comment: yes, I've edited the question

Comment: Why do you have limits ? who's $a$ ? $O$ is just about bounding, which you did in your first 2 inequalities.

Comment: Max is right. Everything from "Also" on is not needed. All you need is to note that $|u| \le k_1k_2|f|$ to show that $u \in O(f)$. But also note that this just shows that $O(O(f)) \subseteq O(f)$. To prove the equality, you must also show that $O(f) \subseteq O(O(f))$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You are right. Thanks for pointing that out!